# Bitcoin core does not have all unconfirmed transactions

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-qt-setup, getmemorypool

I am running `bitcoinqt` and checking for new transaction for payments I made using `getrawmempool`. Payments were made NOT from/to the mentioned `bitcoinqt` wallet address.

As I see some my unconfirmed transactions never come to `getrawmempool`.

Is it expected result or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you got the whole blockchain locally? Have you check number of connectioins to the network?

Comment: it says "8 active connections to Bitcoin network"
And yes, I have whole blockchain locally

Comment: 8 active connections is suspected - should be more

Comment: I opened 8333 port and now have 13 active connections. Is it enough?

Comment: The case is the 8 connections are built-in client. If you have more means that client has ability to get new nodes. It's OK.

Comment: If transaction isn't in memory you won't get it https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getrawmempool

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/33980/2-bitcoinqt-getrawmempool-returns-different-results

Comment: What version of Bitcoin Core? Are you seeing the transactions at all eventually in the wallet?

Comment: Yes, I see new transactions but missing some new transactions made from mycelium wallet. Also these missing transactions I see in blockchain.info but confirmations takes much longer then another which I can see in memory pool. Bitcoin Core version v0.11.2 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

In general, mempools are not guaranteed to be the same node-to-node. The behavior of the reference client is that [once mempools reach 300MB](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/9afbd96919afd1f773e4c2633b0cfd6068e2b228/src/policy/policy.h#L29), the lowest fee tx's [are thrown away](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/6722).

It's possible your node has reached this limit (either because it's 300MB or because your default is much lower) or simply because you're connected to nodes that have the same limitation.